# Dúvida sobre autoload utilizando composer

Tags: php, composer

Eu criei um exemplo bem simples de utilização do *autoload* utilizando o Composer e PSR-7, porém gostaria de entender uma questão, abaixo o que fiz:

Dentro do meu `composer.json`, adicionei o seguinte:

```
"autoload" : {
    "psr-4" : {
        "App\\" : "App/"
    }
}
```

Dentro do diretório `App`, criei uma classe bem simples chamada `Log`:

```
<?php 

namespace App;

class Log {

    public function gravarLog()
    {
        return 'Log gravado com sucesso';
    }
} 

?>
```

E por fim criei um arquivo `index.php`, para realizar o teste, ficou assim:

```
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Log;

$log = new App\Log();
echo $log->gravarLog();
```

Funcionou certinho, porém gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de utilizar o use nesta situação, sem a necessidade de utilizar sempre `require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';` assim como é feito no Laravel, e como eu faço isso? Existe algum padrão, ou uma metodologia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na verdade o Laravel e qualquer outro framework PHP faz esse `require` sem você perceber.

Eles utilizam um conceito chamado *Front Controller*, onde da forma que o PHP funciona, **todas** suas requisições passam por um único arquivo, no caso geralmente é o `index.php`.

Na versão mais recente do Laravel, o seu arquivo `index.php` faz o `require` do *autoload*:

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */
define('LARAVEL_START', microtime(true));

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

Veja [aqui](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/public/index.php#L24) no código.

**Concluindo:** sim, você precisa incluir o *autoload* **pelo menos** uma vez no arquivo principal da sua aplicação, no caso seu `index.php`. Pense que poderia ser pior, pois você não precisa implementar seu [script de *autoload* do zero](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.spl-autoload-register.php) ou incluir todos os arquivos com `require` um de cada vez (que no fundo é o que o *autoload* faz).

Referência:

- [Request Lifecycle do Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/lifecycle)

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno.

Answer (score 2):

Não é possível qualquer arquivo precisa de suas referencias, O laravel também efetua um require conforme pode ser visto no print abaixo:

[image: Importação Autoload Laravel]